# Run if loop in parallel

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have a data set with ~4 million rows that I need to loop over. The data structure is there are repeated IDs that are dependent on each other but data is independent across IDs. For each ID, the [i+1] row is a dependent on [i]. Here is a reproducible example. I do realize that this example is not practical in terms of the inner functions but it is simply a demonstration of the structure I have.

```
set.seed(123)

id1 = rep(1,5)
id2 = rep(2,5)
id3 = rep(3,5)
ids = c(id1,id2,id3)

month = rep(seq(1,5),3)

x = round(rnorm(15,2,5))
y = rep(0,15)

df = as.data.frame(cbind(ids,month,x,y))

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(i>1 && df[i,1]==df[i-1,1]){
    #Main functions go here
    df[i,4] = df[i-1,4]^2+df[i,3]
  }
  else {
    df[i,4] = 1
  }
}
```

The issue is in reality 1000 loops of the real function takes ~90 seconds, so 4 million rows takes days. It isn't feasible for me to run this way. However the IDs are independent and don't need to run together. My question is: is there a way to run this type of loop in parallel? A very non-elegant solution would be to split the file into 50 sections without splitting an ID and simply run the same code on the 50 sub-files. I figure there should be a way to code this though.

**EDIT**: Added month column to show why the rows are dependent on each other. To address two comments below:

1) There are actually 6-7 lines of functions to run. Could I use ifelse() with multiple functions?
2) The desired output would be the full data frame. In reality there are more columns but I need each row in a data frame.

```
   ids month  x      y
1    1     1 -1      1
2    1     2  1      2
3    1     3 10     14
4    1     4  2    198
5    1     5  3  39207
6    2     1 11      1
7    2     2  4      5
8    2     3 -4     21
9    2     4 -1    440
10   2     5  0 193600
11   3     1  8      1
12   3     2  4      5
13   3     3  4     29
14   3     4  3    844
15   3     5 -1 712335
```

**EDIT2:** I've tried applying the foreach() package from another post but it doesn't seem to work. This code will run but I think the issue is the way that rows are distributed among cores. If each row is sequentially sent to a different core then the same ID will never be in the same core.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)


set.seed(123)

id1 = rep(1,5)
id2 = rep(2,5)
id3 = rep(3,5)
ids = c(id1,id2,id3)

month = rep(seq(1,5),3)

x = round(rnorm(15,2,5))
y = rep(0,15)

df = as.data.frame(cbind(ids,month,x,y))

#setup parallel backend to use many processors
cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1) #not to overload your computer
registerDoParallel(cl)

finalMatrix <- foreach(i=1:nrow(df), .combine=cbind) %dopar% {

  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(i>1 && df[i,1]==df[i-1,1]){
      #Main functions go here
      df[i,4] = df[i-1,4]^2+df[i,3]
    }
    else {
      df[i,4] = 1
    }
  }
}
#stop cluster
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: FYI `ifelse` is vectorized

Comment: Please provide few rows of desirable output.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Do you always have the same number of observations for each id? 2. Are all of the manipulations in your function basic mathematical operations? (add, subtract, multiply, divide, exponent, etc...), If so, it's possible this could be executed with matrix operations in a vectorized way.

Comment: 1) No the number of obs is not static. 2) The functions are actually finance related so we end up calling other functions and performing matrix multiplications in each loop. These are definitely bottlenecks. Still I would be interested to hear your solution for a simpler case and work up from there.

Comment: How many distinct IDs are in the dataset (approx.)?

Comment: ~90,000 distinct ids. ~4 million rows in total.

Comment: If you want to speed up some R loops, before trying to parallelize your code, you should try to optimize it by vectorizing it or recoding it with Rcpp.

Comment: Moreover, I don't understand where your computations are independent from each other.

Comment: Based on the dimensions of your data, ~90,000 ids w/ ~45 rows each, i suspect the communication overhead associated with cluster style parallelization might exceed the actual computation being done. _(if you had 45 ids with 90,000 rows each it would be a completely different story, or perhaps if your real functions are far more computationally intensive than shown in your example here)_

Comment: @MattSummersgill: The functions are much, much more computational intensive. There are nested functions and matrix multiplication during every loop. I agree with the example given this doesn't make sense but for my real problem this is necessary.

Comment: @F.Privé Each row's y value is a function of the previous row's y value if the ID is the same. However when the ID is not the same this is not true. The first row for each ID has different logic that is not tied to any other row or ID. This is how they are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `foreach`. Hard to say how it would work in your real life example, at least it works with the testdata ...

First I generate some testdata:

```
# function to generate testdata

genDat <- function(id){

  # observations per id, fixed or random
  n <- 50
  #n <- round(runif(1,5,1000))

  return(

    data.frame(id=id,month=rep(1:12,ceiling(n/12))[1:n],x=round(rnorm(n,2,5)),y=rep(0,n))

  )
}

#generate testdata

testdat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:90000,genDat))


> head(testdat)
  id month  x y
1  1     1  7 0
2  1     2  6 0
3  1     3 -9 0
4  1     4  3 0
5  1     5 -9 0
6  1     6  8 0


> str(testdat)
'data.frame':   4500000 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ month: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ x    : num  7 6 -9 3 -9 8 -4 13 0 5 ...
 $ y    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

So the testdata has ~ 4.5 million rows with 90k unique ids.

Now since your calculations are independent between the IDs, the idea would be to ship off data with unique IDs to each core ... this would ultimately also get rid of the necessity for an `if` or `ifelse` condition.

To do this, I first generate a matrix with start and stop row indices, to split the dataset in unique IDs:

```
id_len <- rle(testdat$id)

ixmat <- cbind(c(1,head(cumsum(id_len$lengths)+1,-1)),cumsum(id_len$lengths))
```

This matrix can then be passed on to `foreach` for running the specific parts in parallel.

In this example I modify your calculations slightly to avoid astronomical values leading to `Inf`.

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(iterators)

cl <- makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)   #create a cluster


r <-  foreach (i = iter(ixmat,by='row')) %dopar% {

  x <- testdat$x[i[1,1]:i[1,2]]
  y <- testdat$y[i[1,1]:i[1,2]]
  y[1] <- 1

  for(j in 2:length(y)){
    #y[j] <- (y[j-1]^2) + x[j] ##gets INF
    y[j] <- y[j-1] + x[j]
    }

  return(y)
}

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Finally you could replace the values in the original dataframe:

```
testdat$y <- unlist(r)
```

As for the time, the foreach loop runs in about 40 seconds on my 8 core machine.

Comment: This is exactly the framework I was thinking of! I am trying to modify your template to my code, since there are actually 9 columns or so that need to run in the loop but I think I can tweak it and test today. Conceptually this is what I was hoping for - send each block of IDs to a core.

Answer (score 3):

So, simply recode your loop with Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector fill_y(const NumericVector& x) {

  int n = x.length();
  NumericVector y(n); y[0] = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    y[i] = pow(y[i - 1], 2) + x[i];
  }
  return y;
}
```

And, to apply it on each group, use **dplyr**:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ids) %>%
  mutate(y2 = fill_y(x))
```

I think this should be fast enough so that you don't need parallelism. 
Actually I ran it on @Val's `testdat` and it took only 2 seconds (with an old computer).

Tell me if it's okay. Otherwise, I'll make a parallel version.

Comment: You make a compelling case to get more comfortable with `C++`, especially on inescapably serial tasks! Using your code with data.table -- `df[,y := fill_y(x), by = ids]` clocks in at  0.35 seconds for me! _(excluding 3.4 seconds of compile time)_

Comment: +1 for speeding it up. You should be a bit more verbose on how to actually use the function (like sourcing it etc.) for people with no prior experience with `Rcpp` - like me.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I actually should store a pre-written sentence for each time I need to explain this. Basically, put that in an ".cpp" file and "Source" it with RStudio. I'm open to better explanations :')

Comment: Thank you for the response! The issue is the functions inside of the loop are actually quite computationally taxing. This is a finance program and the inner loop contains ppmt()/ipmt() functions as well as matrix multiplication. All in all, there are 9 new columns that are a function of the previous row and the current row. That's why I think I need to run in parallel. I'll try this structure out today though.

Answer (score 1):

### Base R Matrix operations and `melt`/`dcast` from `data.table`

As discussed in the comments above, this solution is very specific to the use case in the example, but perhaps might be applicable to your use case.

Using matrix operations and the `dcast.data.table` and `melt.data.table` functions from the `data.table` package to make fast transitions from a long to wide format and back is pretty efficient.

All things considered, the bigger constraint will likely how much RAM you have available than processing time with these methods.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)

id1 = rep(1,5)
id2 = rep(2,5)
id3 = rep(3,5)
ids = c(id1,id2,id3)

month = rep(seq(1,5),3)

x = round(rnorm(15,2,5))
# y = rep(0,15) ## no need to pre-define y with this method

df = as.data.frame(cbind(ids,month,x))
setDT(df) ## Convert to data.table by reference

wide <- dcast.data.table(df, month ~ ids, value.var = "x") ## pivot to 'wide' format

mat <- data.matrix(wide[,-c("month")]) ## Convert to matrix
print(mat)
```

gives

```
      1  2  3
[1,] -1 11  8
[2,]  1  4  4
[3,] 10 -4  4
[4,]  2 -1  3
[5,]  3  0 -1
```

Then operating on it as a matrix:

```
mat[1,] <- 1 ## fill the first row with 1's as in your example

for (i in 2:nrow(mat)){
  mat[i,] = mat[i-1L,]^2 + mat[i,]
}

print(mat)
```

gives

```
         1      2      3
[1,]     1      1      1
[2,]     2      5      5
[3,]    14     21     29
[4,]   198    440    844
[5,] 39207 193600 712335
```

Next, melt back to a long format and then join back to the original data on key columns `ids` and `month`:

```
yresult <- as.data.table(mat) ## convert back to data.table format
yresult[,month := wide[,month]] ## Add back the month column

ylong <- melt.data.table(yresult,
                         id.vars = "month",
                         variable.factor = FALSE,
                         variable.name = "ids",
                         value.name = "y") ## Pivot back to 'long' format

ylong[,ids := as.numeric(ids)] ## reclass ids to match input ids

setkey(ylong, ids, month) ## set keys for join on 'ids' and 'month'
setkey(df, ids,month)

merge(df,ylong) ## join data.table with the result
```

yields the final result:

```
    ids month  x      y
 1:   1     1 -1      1
 2:   1     2  1      2
 3:   1     3 10     14
 4:   1     4  2    198
 5:   1     5  3  39207
 6:   2     1 11      1
 7:   2     2  4      5
 8:   2     3 -4     21
 9:   2     4 -1    440
10:   2     5  0 193600
11:   3     1  8      1
12:   3     2  4      5
13:   3     3  4     29
14:   3     4  3    844
15:   3     5 -1 712335
```

### Scale Testing

To test and illustrate scaling, the function `testData` below generates a data set by cross joining a given number of ids and a given number of months. Then, the function `testFunc` performs the recursive row-wise matrix operations.

```
testData <- function(id_count, month_count) {

  id_vector <- as.numeric(seq_len(id_count))
  months_vector <- seq_len(month_count)

  df <- CJ(ids = id_vector,month = months_vector)
  df[,x := rnorm(.N,0,0.1)]
  return(df)
}

testFunc <- function(df) {
  wide <- dcast.data.table(df,month ~ ids, value.var = "x")

  mat <- data.matrix(wide[,-c("month")])

  mat[1,] <- 1

  for (i in 2:nrow(mat)){
    mat[i,] = mat[i-1L,]^2 + mat[i,]
  }

  yresult <- as.data.table(mat)
  yresult[,month := wide[,month]]

  ylong <- melt.data.table(yresult,
                           id.vars = "month",
                           variable.factor = FALSE,
                           variable.name = "ids",
                           value.name = "y")

  ylong[,ids := as.numeric(ids)]

  setkey(ylong, ids, month)
  setkey(df, ids,month)

  merge(df,ylong)
}
```

#### With 90,000 `ids` and 45 `months`:

```
foo  <- testData(90000,45)

system.time({
  testFunc(foo)
})
```

---

```
   user  system elapsed 
  8.186   0.013   8.201
```

Run-time comes in **under 10 seconds** with a single thread.

#### With 100,000 `ids` and 1,000 `months`:

*This three column input data.table is ~1.9GB*

```
foo  <- testData(1e5,1e3)

system.time({
  testFunc(foo)
})
```

---

```
   user  system elapsed 
 52.790   4.046  57.031
```

A single threaded run-time of less than a minute seems pretty manageable depending on how many times this needs to be run. As always, this could be sped up further by improvements to my code or converting the recursive portion to `C++` using `Rcpp`, but avoiding the mental overhead of learning `C++` and switching between languages in your workflow is always nice!