# R: for loop within a foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, doparallel

## EDIT: Reduced the size of the dataset

A sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:10, each = 80*36), 
             year = rep(rep(1980:2015, each = 80), times = 10),
             day = rep(rep(1:80, times = 36),times = 10),
             rain = runif(10*36*80, min = 0 , max = 5),
             swc = runif(10*36*80,min = 0, max = 50),
             SW.max = rep(runif(10, min = 100, max = 200), each = 80*36),
             SW.ini = runif(10*36*80),
             PETc = runif(10*36*80, min = 0 , max = 1.3),
             SW = NA,
             PAW = NA, 
             aetc = NA)
```

`df` contains daily data (80 days) for 1980-2015 for 10 locations.
For each location X year combination, I want to do following calculation

```
list.result <- list() # create a list to store all results
ptm <- proc.time()
n <- 0

for(i in seq_along(unique(df$loc.id))){

location <- unique(df$loc.id)[i]
print(location)

for(j in seq_along(unique(df$year))){

yr <- unique(df$year)[j]
print(yr)

df_year <- df[df$loc.id == location & df$year == yr,] # subset data for location i and year y

# for the first row of data frame, i need to calculate some values 
SW.ini <- df_year$SW.ini[1] 
SW.max <- df_year$SW.max[1]

df_year$PAW[1] <- SW.ini + df_year$rain[1]
df_year$aetc[1] <- ifelse(df_year$PAW[1] >= df_year$swc[1], 
df_year$PETc[1],(df_year$PAW[1]/df_year$swc[1])*df_year$PETc[1])
df_year$aetc[1] <- ifelse(df_year$aetc[1] > df_year$PAW[1], df_year$PAW[1], df_year$aetc[1])
df_year$SW[1] <- SW.ini + df_year$rain[1] -  df_year$aetc[1]
df_year$SW[1] <- ifelse(df_year$SW[1] > SW.max, SW.max, ifelse(df_year$SW[1] < 0, 0,df_year$SW[1]))

# for row 2 till row n of df_year, I need to do this:
for (day in 2:nrow(df_year)){
df_year$PAW[day] <- df_year$SW[day - 1] + df_year$rain[day]

df_year$aetc[day] <- ifelse(df_year$PAW[day] >= df_year$swc[day], df_year$PETc[day], (df_year$PAW[day]/df_year$swc[day]) * df_year$PETc[day])

df_year$aetc[day] <- ifelse(df_year$aetc[day] > df_year$PAW[day], df_year$PAW[day],df_year$aetc[day])

df_year$SW[day] <- df_year$SW[day - 1] + df_year$rain[day] -  df_year$aetc[day]

df_year$SW[day] <- ifelse(df_year$SW[day] > SW.max,SW.max, ifelse(df_year$SW[day] < 0, 0,df_year$SW[day]))

   }
n <- n + 1
list.result[[n]] <- df_year
}}
proc.time() - ptm
user  system elapsed 
8.64    0.00    8.75

final.dat <- rbindlist(list.result)
```

This loop is sequential and I thought it is a good candidate for foreach in R. I have not really worked with 
foreach so doing some online research brought me to this:

```
  library(doParallel)
  cl <- makeCluster(4) # if I understood this correctly, it assings number of cores to be used 
  registerDoParallel(cl)

  foreach(i = seq_along(unique(df$loc.id)) %dopar% {
    list.result <- list()
    for(j in seq_along(1980:2015)){

      df_year <- df[df$loc.id == unique(df$loc.id)[i] & df$year == unique(df$year)[j],] # subset data for location i and year y

      # for the first row of data frame, i need to calculate some values 
      SW.ini <- df_year$SW.ini[1] 
      SW.max <- df_year$SW.max[1]

      df_year$PAW[1] <- SW.ini + df_year$rain[1]
      df_year$aetc[1] <- ifelse(df_year$PAW[1] >= df_year$swc[1], df_year$PETc[1],(df_year$PAW[1]/df_year$swc[1])*df_year$PETc[1])
      df_year$aetc[1] <- ifelse(df_year$aetc[1] > df_year$PAW[1], df_year$PAW[1], df_year$aetc[1])
      df_year$SW[1] <- SW.ini + df_year$rain[1] -  df_year$aetc[1]
      df_year$SW[1] <- ifelse(df_year$SW[1] > SW.max, SW.max, ifelse(df_year$SW[1] < 0, 0,df_year$SW[1]))

      # for row 2 till row n of df_year, I need to do this:
      for (day in 2:nrow(df_year)){
        df_year$PAW[day] <- df_year$SW[day - 1] + df_year$rain[day]
        df_year$aetc[day] <- ifelse(df_year$PAW[day] >= df_year$swc[day], df_year$PETc[day], (df_year$PAW[day]/df_year$swc[day]) * df_year$PETc[day])
        df_year$aetc[day] <- ifelse(df_year$aetc[day] > df_year$PAW[day], df_year$PAW[day],df_year$aetc[day])
        df_year$SW[day] <- df_year$SW[day - 1] + df_year$rain[day] -  df_year$aetc[day]
        df_year$SW[day] <- ifelse(df_year$SW[day] > SW.max,SW.max, ifelse(df_year$SW[day] < 0, 0,df_year$SW[day]))

      }
      list.result[[j]] <- df_year
    }
    dat <- rbindlist(list.result)
    fwrite(dat,paste0(i,"dat.csv"))
 }
```

My questions are:

1) Is the above data a good candidate for foreach

2) There is a for-loop within the foreach. Does that make sense?

3) How do I make the above foreach run and return all the results

Comment: I would write a function for 1 location and then use `lapply` or `purrr::map` to loop through all 3000 locations. That would get rid of 1 loop

Comment: For the 2nd loop, looks like you might be able to use `Reduce`. See these links for examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412516/how-to-write-a-cumulative-calculation-in-data-table | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624110/referring-to-previous-row-in-calculation

Comment: We understand you have a large dataset and the above code is slow.  Could you reduce the size of your above sample from 39 million rows to maybe ~100.  This will allow others to run your code and offer tested improvement suggestions.

Comment: Okay. I can do that. Give me 1 minute

Comment: Updating an element in a data.frame column copies the _entire_ column; gain considerable speed-up by updating plain vectors during the iteration, and assigning them at the end. Consider `min()` / `max()` rather some of your `ifelse()`.

Comment: If the data were a (year.location) x day matrix,then the iteration by day could be vectorized across year.location, resulting in a 3000 x 15 speed-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To address your three questions:**

1. **I don't think so.** *(More computationally efficient methods can completely eliminate the need for adding more processing power.)*
2. **Nothing inherently bad about for loops within parallel processing.** *(In fact, the more computation that needs to be done on each chunk, the more likely parallel methods could give a performance improvement.)*
3. *(Not applicable if you use the methods below)*

### Using `Rcpp` and `data.table` instead

Compiling the logic with C++ and applying it by group using data.table grouping operations gives a ~2,000x speed-up from your baseline, far greater than you might hope to get by parallelizing.

On your original example, which had **39,420,000 rows**, this executes on my machine in **1.883 seconds**; and on the revised one with **28,800 rows**, this executes in **0.004 seconds**

```
library(data.table)
library(Rcpp)
```

Define and compile a `C++` function, `CalcSW()` inline in the R script:

*One note: counting in `C`/`C++` starts at `0`, unlike `R`, which starts at `1`-- that's why the indices are different here*

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
List CalcSW(NumericVector SW_ini,
            NumericVector SW_max,
            NumericVector rain,
            NumericVector swc,
            NumericVector PETc) {

  int n = SW_ini.length();
  NumericVector SW(n);
  NumericVector PAW(n);
  NumericVector aetc(n);

  double SW_ini_glob = SW_ini[0];
  double SW_max_glob = SW_max[0];

  SW[0] = SW_ini_glob;
  PAW[0] = SW[0] + rain[0];

  if (PAW[0] > swc[0]){
    aetc[0] = PETc[0];
  } else {
    aetc[0] = PAW[0]/swc[0]*PETc[0];
  }

  if (aetc[0] > PAW[0]){
    aetc[0] = PAW[0];
  }

  SW[0] = SW[0] + rain[0] - aetc[0];

  if(SW[0] > SW_max_glob){
    SW[0] = SW_max_glob;
  }

  if(SW[0] < 0){
    SW[0] = 0;
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {

    PAW[i] = SW[i-1] + rain[i];

    if (PAW[i] > swc[i]){
      aetc[i] = PETc[i];
    } else {
      aetc[i] = PAW[i]/swc[i]*PETc[i];
    }

    if (aetc[i] > PAW[i]){
      aetc[i] = PAW[i];
    }

    SW[i] = SW[i-1] + rain[i] - aetc[i];

    if(SW[i] > SW_max_glob){
      SW[i] = SW_max_glob;
    }

    if(SW[i] < 0){
     SW[i] = 0;
    }
  }
  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("SW") = SW,
                            Rcpp::Named("PAW") = PAW,
                            Rcpp::Named("aetc") = aetc);
}')
```

Create data.table

```
df <- data.table(loc.id = rep(1:10, each = 80*36), 
                 year = rep(rep(1980:2015, each = 80), times = 10),
                 day = rep(rep(1:80, times = 36),times = 10),
                 rain = runif(10*36*80, min = 0 , max = 5),
                 swc = runif(10*36*80,min = 0, max = 50),
                 SW_max = rep(runif(10, min = 100, max = 200), each = 80*36),
                 SW_ini = runif(10*36*80),
                 PETc = runif(10*36*80, min = 0 , max = 1.3),
                 SW = as.numeric(NA),
                 PAW = as.numeric(NA), 
                 aetc = as.numeric(NA))

setkey(df, loc.id, year, day)
```

Execute the function `CalcSW()` on the `df` for each combination of `loc.id` and `year`, assign returned values to the three columns simultaneously:

```
system.time({
  df[,  c("SW","PAW","aetc") := CalcSW(SW_ini,
                                       SW_max,
                                       rain,
                                       swc,
                                       PETc), keyby = .(loc.id, year)]
})
```

...

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.004   0.000   0.004
```

Results:

```
head(df)
```

...

```
   loc.id year day       rain       swc   SW_max     SW_ini      PETc       SW      PAW       aetc
1:      1 1980   1 0.35813251 28.360715 177.3943 0.69116310 0.2870478 1.038675 1.049296 0.01062025
2:      1 1980   2 1.10331116 37.013022 177.3943 0.02742273 0.4412420 2.125335 1.396808 0.01665171
3:      1 1980   3 1.76680011 32.509970 177.3943 0.66273062 1.1071233 3.807561 2.483467 0.08457420
4:      1 1980   4 3.20966558  8.252797 177.3943 0.12220454 0.3496968 6.840713 4.165693 0.17651342
5:      1 1980   5 1.32498191 14.784203 177.3943 0.66381497 1.2168838 7.573160 7.198845 0.59253503
6:      1 1980   6 0.02547458 47.903637 177.3943 0.21871598 1.0864713 7.418750 7.931292 0.17988449
```

I'm not 100% positive I implemented your logic perfectly, but the logic should be pretty straightforward to tweak where I may have missed something, I implemented it in a very similar manner to how you laid it out.

---

One other note: It's way easier to write `C++` with auto-indenting and code highlighting *(whether you're using RStudio or Emacs)* you get if you create a separate file, named something like `TestCode.cpp`formatted like below.

Then, you can either use `Rcpp::sourceCpp("TestCode.cpp")` to compile your function in your R Script, or you can copy and paste everything except for the first three lines as a character string into as an argument of `Rcpp::cppFunction()` like I did above.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List CalcSW(NumericVector SW_ini,
                     NumericVector SW_max,
                     NumericVector rain,
                     NumericVector swc,
                     NumericVector PETc) {

  int n = SW_ini.length();
  NumericVector SW(n);
  NumericVector PAW(n);
  NumericVector aetc(n);

  double SW_ini_glob = SW_ini[0];
  double SW_max_glob = SW_max[0];

  SW[0] = SW_ini_glob;
  PAW[0] = SW[0] + rain[0];

  if (PAW[0] > swc[0]){
    aetc[0] = PETc[0];
  } else {
    aetc[0] = PAW[0]/swc[0]*PETc[0];
  }

  if (aetc[0] > PAW[0]){
    aetc[0] = PAW[0];
  }

  SW[0] = SW[0] + rain[0] - aetc[0];

  if(SW[0] > SW_max_glob){
    SW[0] = SW_max_glob;
  }

  if(SW[0] < 0){
    SW[0] = 0;
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {

    PAW[i] = SW[i-1] + rain[i];

    if (PAW[i] > swc[i]){
      aetc[i] = PETc[i];
    } else {
      aetc[i] = PAW[i]/swc[i]*PETc[i];
    }

    if (aetc[i] > PAW[i]){
      aetc[i] = PAW[i];
    }

    SW[i] = SW[i-1] + rain[i] - aetc[i];

    if(SW[i] > SW_max_glob){
      SW[i] = SW_max_glob;
    }

    if(SW[i] < 0){
      SW[i] = 0;
    }
  }
  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("SW") = SW,
                            Rcpp::Named("PAW") = PAW,
                            Rcpp::Named("aetc") = aetc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Matt. This is a very detailed answer. I will have to go through it since I am not familiar with Rcpp and will accept (upvote) your answer once I managed to understand it. Please bear with me. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: No rush at all! I don't use `Rcpp` very often myself, so this was a good chance to brush up on some basics. The only reason I used it here is because this problem has an element _(dependence on previous row's calculation)_ that makes a for-loop unavoidable -- these are the cases where compiled `c++` can really shine. 99.9% of the code I write is plain `R`  + `data.table` since it's usually fast enough, but @f-privé 's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113467/run-if-loop-in-parallel/) inspired me to consider it for these kind of problems.

Comment: This proved to be the most useful thing I have learnt. So thank you very much. Minor point: 1)  `PAW[i] = SW[i-1] + rain[0]` should be `PAW[i] = SW[i-1] + rain[i]` if I understand this code correctly. 2) What does `n = SW_ini.length()` do?

Comment: Happy to help! 1) Typo on my part, edited to reflect your comment. 2) this is the C++ equivalent of R’s length() function. It defines n as an integer that represents the length of the input vector SW_ini

Comment: Why does it take faster in C++ than in R? I mean you did the same thing I did in R except you used Rccp to define the function? Are loops inherently faster in C++. Sorry this is off topic but I thought I have similar scripts that take long and I could use this approach to make them fast as well.

Comment: C and C++ are statically typed, compiled languages, whereas R is a dynamically typed, interpreted language. Compiling the logic to machine code instructions before-hand does make it inherently faster for simple for loops like this that need to be executed millions of times. That being said, I'd recommend reading 
 this whole page https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/performance.html (with a particular focus on profvis) , there are many other things you can do within R _(i.e. using `data.table` instead of base R data frames)_ to get get orders of magnitude speed-ups as well.

Comment: Just to note that the C++ code _does not_ do the same thing as the R code, in particular it allocates new vectors and fills them, rather than updating columns of an existing data frame. It also uses more straight-forward logic (compare Matt's simple if statements with your nested ifelse()). Check out how much faster your R code is if you implement these approaches at the R level (i.e., my `fill1()`).

Answer (score 1):

This code replaces the inner loop

```
clamp <- function(x, low, high)
    min(high, max(low, x))

fill1 <- function(df) {
    rain <- df$rain
    swc <- df$swc
    PETc <- df$PETc

    SW0 <- df$SW.ini[1]
    SW.max <- df$SW.max[1]

    SW <- PAW <- aetc <- numeric(nrow(df))

    for (day in seq_along(rain)) {
        PAW[day] <- SW0 + rain[day]

        if (PAW[day] >= swc[day]) {
            aetc0 <- PETc[day]
        } else {
            aetc0 <- (PAW[day] / swc[day]) * PETc[day]
        }
        aetc[day] <- min(PAW[day], aetc0)

        SW0 <- SW[day] <- clamp(PAW[day] -  aetc[day], 0, SW.max)
    }

    list(SW = SW, PAW = PAW, aetc = aetc)
}
```

and is about 60x faster than the implementation in the original question. Note that this is the approach taken in C++, i.e., allocate and update new vectors, rather than existing parts of the data.frame; this is a big part of the performance difference, and the benefit can be obtained WITHOUT Rcpp.

This is a generalization (very light testing!) to iterate on a location.year x day matrix

```
pclamp <- function(x, low, high)
    pmin(high, pmax(low, x))

fill2 <- function(rain, swc, PETc, SW0, SW.max) {

    SW <- PAW <- aetc <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(rain), ncol = ncol(rain))

    for (day in seq_len(ncol(rain))) {
        PAW[, day] <- SW0 + rain[, day]

        aetc0 <- PETc[, day]
        idx <- PAW[, day] < swc[, day]
        aetc0[idx] <- (PAW[idx, day] / swc[idx, day]) * PETc[idx, day]
        aetc[, day] <- pmin(PAW[, day], aetc0)

        SW0 <- SW[, day] <- pclamp(PAW[, day] -  aetc[, day], 0, SW.max)
    }

    list(SW = SW, PAW = PAW, aetc = aetc)
}
```

with inputs from the original, assuming the input is sorted by year, location, and day

```
days <- 80
rain <- matrix(df$rain, ncol=days, byrow=TRUE)
swc <- matrix(df$swc, ncol=days, byrow=TRUE)
PETc <- matrix(df$PETc, ncol=days, byrow=TRUE)
SW.ini <- df$SW.ini[df$day == 1]
SW.max <- df$SW.max[df$day == 1]

result <- fill2(rain, swc, PETc, SW.ini, SW.max)
```

It is about 15x faster than `fill1()` on a per-location.date basis, for the subset of data in the question. The operation on the sample data takes about 10 milliseconds, and about 10 seconds for the full data -- 5x slower than Matt's C++ solution but still a very substantial improvement over the  original and employing basic R techniques that will improve code in many different areas.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Let me test these solutions and come back to you. Regards